# Link with parameter in Django templates

Tags: django, parameters, hyperlink, django-templates

How can I make a link with parameter in Django tepmlates ?

I try to do something like

```
<a href="/member/profile/edit/code=" % {{ sal.id }}> Edit</a>
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of doin it:

```
<a href="/member/profile/edit/code={{ sal.id }}"> Edit</a>
```

But a preferred method is to use a URL tag.

```
{% url edit_profile sal.id %}
```

where, in your `urls.py` you have an entry with name `edit_profile`

You can also, if you want, reverse the URLs in the model in a method, say `get_absolute_url` and call that method, like:

```
{{sal.get_absolute_url}}
```

where, the said method is defined as follows:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ['edit_profile',(self.id,)]
```

Comment: I had to use `{% url 'edit_profile' sal.id %}` otherwise an error was raised; running django 1.8.7